# how do shutdown content provider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I would like to terminate the current instance of my custom content provider. I would like my content provider to terminate such as when my application is logging off. On the subsequent URI trigger, i would like my content provider to reinstantiate itself via calling onCreate().

Do you know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by shutdown the `ContentProvider`? And why do you want to do this?

Comment: If you need this in anything but a test, change you design.

Comment: i wish to implement logging off function in the app such that the user profile data in ContentProvider can be completely wiped off in the ContentProvider. This way when a new and different user attempt to login again onto the app on the same device, a new instance of ContentProvider can be restarted with a new fresh database.

Comment: eventually I have to resort to implementing database switching within the context of ContentProvider. I am wondering whether there is an easier way to do this based on the ContentProvider framework. I noticed there is a shutdown function in Honeycomb, I did not try that though coz I would like it to function in 2.3.3 based devices as well.